# get values from PHP var_dump from XML string

Tags: php, var-dump

I have XML string $input which is received from SOAP service

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($input);
echo var_dump($xml). "<br />";
```

gives output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(5) "False"
  ["error"]=>
  string(13) "Login Failure"
```

How to get 'False' value or any in its place into an variable?

Comment: Do you mean ```$xml["result"]```?

Comment: this is PHP OOP 101. How to access an object property

Comment: @Snicksie `$xml["result"]` -> this will throw an error of type E_ERROR, because you can't access an object like an array :)

Comment: Thanks for all negative votes. I'm new in PHP. Can't figured how to do it. that's why I asked.

Comment: Just a tip: Use google with keywords from your output: php, object, access or something else, it's really easy to find with your favorite search engine :)

Comment: @Florian I clearly should learn to look closer, I didn't see the "Object", but automatically assumed an array. Too early in the morning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
$yourvar = $xml->result;
```

To get "False" (or the value of result in your Xml).

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of `result` from

```
 object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(5) "False"
  ["error"]=>
  string(13) "Login Failure"
```

you can use:

```
$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($input);
echo $xmlObject->result;
```

---

Output:

```
False
```

---

Learn more about [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) with [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)